# Odd error in Xcode How should I resolve this?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm new to iOS development so this may be something simple. I'm getting the error pictured when trying to compile. From what I read this can be resolved by setting Release to none under optimisation level unfortunately this did not solve my issue so any advice is greatly appreciated. This is the error I'm getting

[image]

Comment: There is nothing odd about it.  I see it from time to time.

Comment: First `Clean` and then `Build` your project though `Product` menu in Xcode. Sometimes Xcode build caches gets corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

K so I actually figured this out more or less. It has something you do with pods, by commenting out

```
//module zlib [system] {
 // header "include.h"
 // link "z"
 //{
```

it resolved the issue.